# Incorrect Password Value on Save in SocialEngine / Zend Framework

Tags: php, zend-framework, socialengine

I'm using a custom script to update SocialEngine user password. However, after setting the value properly, it is changed when saved. I can't figure out why.

```
$user = Engine_Api::_()->getItemTable('user')->fetchRow...//etc

$user->password = md5($coresalt.$newpass.$usersalt);

echo $user->password; // Correct value f115c8dddcd360bb7ccd8f801520036a

$user->save(); // Why does it get changed here?

echo $user->password; // Incorrect value 30d04d29530332248833ddfbfe6352f8
```

Comment: What are the values you're getting?

Comment: Added the values in the edit. I had to just bypass the framework and use: UPDATE engine4_users SET password = MD5(CONCAT('engine4_core_settings core.secret value','$newpassword',salt)) WHERE email

Answer (score -1):

You can just update engine4_users by setting the password as follows:

```
password = MD5(CONCAT('engine4_core_settings core.secret value','$newpassword',salt))
```